# Jquery Ajax GET method not passing variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get, preventdefault

The below URL works fine:

```
index.php?page=search_result&maker=Any
```

I want to get into this URL from another page using Jquery Ajax function.
Here is my Ajax call:

```
$(function(){

    $(".by_maker").on('click',function(){

        var c_maker = $(this).attr('href');

         $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               datatype: "html",
               url: "index.php?page=search_result",
               data: "maker="+c_maker,
               success: function(response){
                       html(response);} 
           });
    });
});
```

I like to get the value of 'maker' from the href like below html:

```
<a class="by_maker" href="toyota">Toyota</a>
```

NB: there is not 'form' and 'input' elements. If I click on the Toyota link its not going to the desired URL!!! So, what am I doing wrong??? 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use e.preventDefault(); for 'a' click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `return:false;` to the event handler to stop the default action.

```
$(".by_maker").on('click',function(){

    var c_maker = $(this).attr('href');

     $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           datatype: "html",
           url: "index.php?page=search_result",
           data: "maker="+c_maker,
           success: function(response){
                   html(response);} 
       });
       return false;
});
```

Alternatively, you can pass in the `event` to the callback function, and `preventDefault();`

```
$(".by_maker").on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: As described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false
return false and preventDefault are not the same

Comment: @SergeyKochetov It's a nice write up, but I never said `the same`, i said, alternatively, he may do choose to use this. People are such head hunters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
But sorry to say I tried with both the options; putting "return false" and preventDefault(). It seems nothing is working ...

Answer (score 0):

Please use prevent default so it will not be redirect to any where. or just remove "href" from

```
    $(".by_maker").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var c_maker = $(this).attr('href');

         $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               datatype: "html",
               url: "index.php?page=search_result",
               data: "maker="+c_maker,
               success: function(response){
                       html(response);} 
           });
    });
```

OR

Keep jquery click same as it is now

`<a class="by_maker">Toyota</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the  event.preventDefault() to prevent the default action:

```
    $(function(){
    $(".by_maker").on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var c_maker = $(this).attr('href');

     $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           datatype: "html",
           url: "index.php?page=search_result",
           data: "maker="+c_maker,
           success: function(response){
                   html(response);} 
       });
     });
   });
```

Comment: after adding the preventDefault() event nothing changes. Now if I click on that 'a', it goes no where...